# what is the technical reason that selenium can not locate and click on client server web element applications

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

What is the technical reason that selenium can not test client server applications?
I can find web element by xpath or id but I get error:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tbody/tr/td[1]"}

<tbody> 
<tr child="yes" grp="grp0"> 
<td id="30662a_TD_942a4ce9-678f-4152-9a0d-353032" 
    class="menuHeaderMain_menuItem menuItem_selected" 
    valign="middle" nowrap="nowrap" height="20" align="center"   
    onclick="javascript:menus_MenuItemSelected('f9ac9709-7024-42bd-884f-30662a9ed8a5‌​', 
                                               '942a4ce9-678f-4152-9a0d-35303257b7cb',
                                               '4b231bc2-d418-43c0-a4ce-498f58a8ea65');
                        menus_ShowMenu('MainSubMenu_Incidents', 'Menu_SubMain', 'menu_SubMenu', false)" 
    name="f9ac9709-7024-42bd-884f-30662a9ed8a5_MENU_TD" 
    style="cursor:pointer; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">Ticketing</td>
```

Comment: I tried like this also: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[1][text()='Ticketing']")).click();

Comment: This looks ok, the page or the table is probably not yet loaded, so need some webdriverwait or something like that for this.

Comment: Thanks for replay, I already have 30second wait driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); this is the complete error: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tbody/tr/td[1][text()='Ticketing']"}
Command duration or timeout: 30.11 seconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: finally I found the problem:
The html page was in the fram and I add only this line before locating the element.

driver.switchTo().frame(0); and then:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td[1]")).click();